# How to use an enum declared somewhere in my header file?

Tags: c++, header-files

I am beginner user of C++ and I am having this problem since yesterday. 
I have two header files:
'Builder.hpp' which includes declaration and definition of some enums and structs:

```
#ifndef BUILDER_HPP
    #define BUILDER_HPP

    #ifdef _DEFAULT_INCLUDES
        #include <AsDefault.h>
    #endif

    #include "../EcoLibs/EcoComLib/OpcUaCom.hpp"
    #include "LineCoordEngine.hpp"

    //Builder class help types
    enum BuildOpcUaType_enum
    {
      //Some stuff
    };

    enum BuildVariableTypes_enum
    {
        //Some stuff
    };

    struct BuildOpcUaLists_type
    {
        //Some stuff
    };

    //Builder class
    class Builder
    {
        public:
            Builder();
            ~Builder();

            Machine *BuildOpcUaMachine(char serverUrl[UA_MAX_STRING], BuildOpcUaLists_type *lists, BuildOpcUaType_enum uaType);
            DataExchanger *BuildDataExchanger(unsigned short int machineIndex, unsigned short int machineTypeIndex);

        private:
            void CreateOpcUaList(//stuff);                      
            void CreateCharNumber(//stuff);
            //Private variables declaration
    };

#endif
```

The second header file is: 'Parser.hpp'. 
 I want to declare a variable of type 'BuildOpcUaType_enum' which is defined in 'Builder.hpp'. I included 'Builder.hpp' in 'Parser.hpp', but still getting an error saying:
BuildOpcUaType_enum does not name a type.

Parser.hpp:

```
#ifndef BUILDER_HPP
#define BUILDER_HPP

#include "Builder.hpp" 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Attributes{
    string name;
    string value;
};

BuildOpcUaType_enum en;
class Parser{
    private:
        //Variables:
        Attributes attributes[10]; 
        unsigned int BufferIds[200];
        string connectionStrings[20];
        unsigned long int nFileLength, nOpenFileIdent, nXMLReaderIdent; 
        unsigned short int length, noOfOpenedStructs, readListIndex, writeListIndex, readListDestIndex, writeListSrcIndex;
        string comType, sErrorMessage, sStatusText, sXMLElementName, sXMLElementValue;
        string structNameAttValues[10];
        unsigned int TagId_Read[200];
        unsigned int TagId_Write[200];
        unsigned short int xmlData[10000];

        //Boolean variables:
        bool isArrayTag, isBufferIdTag, isDatatypeTag, isNameTag, bStart, isTagIdTag;

        //Constants:
        string sFilePath;
        string sDeviceName;

        //The rest? 
        BuildOpcUaType_enum en;

    public:
        Parser();
        ~Parser();
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your include guard in both header files is `BUILDER_HPP`. You need to use a unique one for each file (that's why it is usually the filename).

As it stands, you are not actually including anything from `Builder.hpp`, because `#define BUILDER_HPP` happens before `#include "Builder.hpp"` in `Parser.hpp` and so the include guard `#ifndef BUILDER_HPP` evaluates to false.

Comment: took the liberty of fixing your `s

Comment: You are right. I have fixed that. Now I am getting a bunch of other errors:
declaration of C function 'double atof(const char*)' conflicts with...
previous declaration 'float atof(long unsigned int)' here
declaration of C function 'int atoi (const char*)' conflicts with...
previous declaration 'long int atoi(long unsigned int)' here

Comment: @DhiaaEddinAnabtawi Happy fixing :) Feel free to ask another question if you get stuck.

Comment: @DhiaaEddinAnabtawi As i said: ask a new question if you have further problems.